# How do you implement a long tap on an actionbar tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am migrating the app source from Tabhost to Fragments and ActionBar. I had implemented long clicks on each tab on the tabhost.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      //some logic
    }
});
```

However, when it comes to new design there is no such long click listener for action bar tab.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround help method. Long press cannot be set directly but this works.

Basically it is getting tab View via custom view and setting long click listener on it.

```
public static void setTabLongClickListener(Context context, ActionBar.Tab tab, View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener)
    {
        //get previous view to ensure correct state after setting long click listener
        View previousCustomView = tab.getCustomView();

        //some view to get parent tab view
        View view = new View(context);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
        ((View)view.getParent()).setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

        //return back removed custom view
        tab.setCustomView(previousCustomView);
    }
```

Tested on normal ActionBar, Support AppCompat and ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I prefer to use the default action bar listener methods which is quite straightforward.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me (on ActionBar compat 19.1.0) - the long click listener is never fired. The onTabReselected() works correctly.